# Poisson approximation of Binomial distribution

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability

Given a problem:

*A textbook is published in $100,000$ copies. The probability that the textbook is incorrectly bound is $0,0001$. Find the probability that the print run contains exactly $5$ of defective books*

**My attempt to solve the problem:**

Let $p$ the probability that one copy is defective, and $q = 1 - p$ the probability that the copy is not defective. The probability that the print run contains exactly $5$ of defective books:

$$\mathbb{P}\left ( X=5 \right )=C^{1000}_5\cdot 0,0001^5\cdot 0,9999^{99995}$$

Let's use the Poisson formula

$$\mathbb{P}\left ( X=k \right )
\approx \frac{e^{-10}\cdot 10^5}{5!}\approx 0,378\approx 3,8\% $$

*Can you tell me if I've made the right decision?*

Comment: That Poisson approximation to the binomial distribution is reasonable here.  The first (with a couple of extra $0$s in $C^{100000}_5$) is about $0.03782949$ and the second about $0.03783327$

Comment: Typo:  should be $.0378$ for the Poisson approximation, not $.378$ as you wrote.

Comment: So I've decided correctly?